# Apache VirtualHost Defaulting to "It Works!" Page

Tags: macos, apache, symfony, xampp

OS: **macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.3)**
Environment: **XAMPP stack**
Virtual Host Domain: **symphart.test**
Symfony Path: **/opt/lampp/htdocs/symphart/**
Symfony Public Path: **/opt/lampp/htdocs/symphart/public/**
Symfony version: **4**

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 symphart.test
```

**/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/symphart/"
   ServerName symphart.test
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type `symphart.test` in browser as the URL, I'm taken to the default XAMPP "It Works!" page:

> It works!

When I type `localhost` in browser as the URL, I am taken to the same page.:

> It works!

When I type `localhost:8080/symphart/public`, It correctly directs me to the application.

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

Comment: Sounds like you might have two webservers running: one on 80, the other on 8080.

Comment: *(...) with a XAMPP stack* and then a couple of lines further: `/opt/lampp/..`. Seems you're configuring one and using the other.

Comment: Hi Loek -- I'm actually using the correct filepath there.  When I change directory in the xampp-provided terminal to the application, and run **pwd**, the output is as follows: **root@debian:/opt/lampp/htdocs/symphart/public#**